# Comparing images of different pixels using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I want to compare two images of different size and resolution, but having some similarity. I am doing the code in OpenCV. Are there any functions available for this task? I need some measure of match between the images so that I can plot the difference between them.

Comment: Why not resizing the image ? "measure of match" is quite fuzzy, can you precise your need ?

Comment: @xiawi , I tried resizing but it did not work ,  though i was able to resize and subtract the second image from first image , It was not so precise . Features which were identified was inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me what you are looking for is a way how to approach your problem.

The task you are trying to solve is called image registration, which variant really depends on your images.

Comment: could you please assist me on how to proceed with image registration

Comment: As I said, it really depends on the kind of images you have.